# Quartz.NET with Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, quartz.net

I setup Ninject in ASP.NET MVC3 like explained here [Using Binaries from Github](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application/a360b12b16b9a0d258ae8a8089d42940edf0530d)

And now I want to setup Quartz.NET, but with Ninject implemented my job is never executed. Before I implement Ninject, my job is executed like expected. Why? And what's the solution?

Thank you for your help! **:)**

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    (...)       
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        kernel.Bind<IUploadRepository>().To<UploadRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<StocksDB>().To<StocksDB>().InRequestScope();

        return kernel;
    }

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        // Quartz.NET scheduler
        var factory = new Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
        var scheduler = factory.GetScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        // construct job info
        var jobDetail = new Quartz.JobDetail("myJob", null, typeof(DumbJob));
        var trigger = new Quartz.SimpleTrigger("myTrigger", null, DateTime.UtcNow, null, Quartz.SimpleTrigger.RepeatIndefinitely, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));            
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);             
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but you probably should be using NuGet to add the current Ninject.MVC3 code to your project.  It uses Web.Activator and no longer requires that you derive from NinjectHttpApplication -- which I suspect is your problem.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! But, I'm using Visual Studio Express and if I'm not wrong, NuGet is a extension to Visual Studio.

Comment: looks like that is still true, but they have plans for supporting more Express versions in the future (the do support VS Web Dev Express).

Comment: @tvanfosson I thought that VS Express versions didn't allow extensions! Your suspection was right, without NinjectHttpApplication Quartz is working! Thank you! **;)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a Ninject related problem. You simply forgot to keep a reference to the scheduler. It's immediately garbage collected after OnApplicationStarted.

Comment: @David @Remo gloor: Remo you should include an `@David` so tardy follow-uppers will get reminded quicker. Else comments like this only get seen by loyal followers!

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink: Thanks for the info. I didn't know about that

Comment: Having said that, I made the comment before [this post's implications](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/r-i-p-envelope-hello-improved-user-pages/) had sunk in - its now harder. Either way its impossible to track comment responses without @ing!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own Ninject ISchedulerFactory for quartz.net.

Default factory is going to create new DumbJob(). And i believe you are trying to inject something in DumbJob so you need to create instance of DumbJob with ninject in your own scheduler factory.

Also you can use mvc3 ninject kernel in that factory.

Comment: Issue mentioned by Remo is defiantly a problem, but looking at your code looks like it should atleast fire it once before it get's garbage collected as it's firing now.